# TYPO3: how to cache just some parts in an extension plugin

Tags: html, caching, flash, mp4, typo3

I have this extension showing some customer data plus an embedded video (MP4).
It consists of a cached Plugin, because the data isn't changed, unless someone in the TYPO3-Backend makes changes to it and clears the Cache.

We wan't to use the new HTML5 Video-Tag to be able to play videos on iPhones/iPads & Co. which don't have Flash. To not have to store multiple videofiles on our servers for each customer, i made a fallback-method for flash-browsers (e.g. Firefox, which won't play MP4-Videos in the HTML5-Tag *hurray*). This method checks the Users Browser-Agent and upon this takes the corresponding Video-Tag (either FlahsPlayer or HTML5).

And here now comes the problem: if I clear Cache in TYPO3-Backend and then load the plugin with Firefox (uses Flash), then if I afterwards load the page on the iPhone, i get the cached version with Flashplayer.
If however i clear TYPO3-Cache and then load the page with an iPhone, then the Firefox on a PC would afterwards get the HTML5-Version (which doesn't work with MP4).

Now the question: is it possible to just cache some parts of a plugin?
I mean: the static customer data won't change that often and therefore caching would be perfect. But the Browser-Agent/used Video-Tag should be checked every time.
I didn't find anything - or i searched the wrong way...

Comment: Why are you doing this on the server side? We usually use videojs (videojs.com) on TYPO3 websites an decide on the client side which video to serve. That way, TYPO3 (and reverse proxies like varnish) can cache the website fully..

Comment: Because on this plattform i want to rely on javascript as less as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to alter the rendering of some extensions to allow a part to be rendered non-cached. That's usually possible if the extension allows to alter the parts with your custom `stdWrap` settings (e.g. tt_news allows that). Unfortunately, that's usually not the case.

The other option might be what David suggested. Having two **[PAGE](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/6/#id2630646)** objects defined each with different `typeNum` and extension rendering of the video while the `PAGE` object is than chosen by TYPO3 depending on the *&type* GET attribute in the URL.

Comment: What do you mean by "Unfortunately, that's usually not the case." => I should not do that because it's bad practice?  Concerning the TYPE-Param: do i understand this correctly if I assume, that if a visitor calls http://mypage.com/somepage then he should be first redirected to http://mypage.com/somepage?type=2 (e.g. when he's on an iPhone) and then uppon this he will get the different content?

Comment: No, by that sentence I meant that most of the extensions unfortunately don't support it. Concerning the problem, where do you currently perform the user-agent detection?

Comment: See my other answer. I've just realized that with Typoscript conditions you should be getting different results as for each condition different cache version is stored.

Comment: Currently i detect User-Agent in the PHP-Method where i assemble the video-Tag.

Comment: Then I suggest you switch the detection to the Typoscript condition. You can either use the built-in detection `[browser]` or if you need to, use custom evaluation in the condition `[userFunc]`. This will give you 2 cached versions of the page. Inside the condition you either set the settings that will produce different rendering for iPhone OR you set some directive that will help your custom method detect that the rendering is being done using this condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a **[Typoscript condition](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/references/doc_core_tsref/4.5.1/view/1/4/)** for the user-agent detection and inside define, re-define any settings, including the type of rendering for different browsers. TYPO3 creates a different cache version for each condition. That's actually why too many conditions result in a growth of the cache table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can use the type-parameter to have virtual 2 pages with your plugin. Then you can decide when an iphone or a firefox loads the page with simple Typo3 conditions. The type-parameter is used for example for a print-page of the current page. Unfortunatly this doesn't work:

```
page = PAGE
page.typeNum = 1
stuff = CASE
stuff.key.field = typeNum
stuff.default = TEXT
stuff.default.value = Default
stuff.1 = TEXT
stuff.1.value = One
```

I always get the text default in my browser window and I don't know how to force a typenum, too.

Comment: What do you mean by "type-parameter"? I'm not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: See my answer, I've fixed my answer.

Comment: You don't have an example for something like that, don't you? Never done something like that before... I mean in combination with a different PHP-Method-Call

Comment: Now I don't know if I understand you. You can easily google for the type-parameter and if I understand the question you don't have to worry about the cache because the type-parameter match exactly what your are asking for?

Comment: The type-param itself I know it. But see my Comment in cascaval's Post - maybe then you see what i mean

Comment: @Stefan: Fixed my answer, it doesn't seem to work with typenum.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your help cascaval and David.

For anyone looking for the same thing, here the detailed code how I finally solved it:

1. Set a plugin setting via Setup & Constants
2. Set some conditions with the defined setting
3. Implement the the PHP-Method

**in setup.txt:**

```
plugin.tx_myext_pi3_item.is_flash_browser = {$plugin.tx_myext_pi3_item.is_flash_browser}
```

**In constants.txt:**

```
# cat=tx_myext/Browser Capabilities/21; type=boolean; label= Browser-Agent Switch:Switch used to differentiate between flash based and HTML5 based browsers (e.g. for rendering different players).  
plugin.tx_myext_pi3_item.is_flash_browser = 1
```

**In TypoScript I set the following configuration:**

```
# Default browser is assumed HTML5 capable:  
plugin.tx_myext.is_flash_browser = 0

# Browser Agent: MSIE prior to version 9.  
[browser = msie] && [version = <9]  
  plugin.tx_myext.is_flash_browser = 1  
[global]

# Browser Agent: Firefox or Opera browser.  
[useragent = *Firefox*] || [useragent = *Opera*]  
  plugin.tx_myext.is_flash_browser = 1  
[global]

# Browser Agent: Google Chrome prior to version 5.  
[useragent = *Chrome*] && [version = <5]  
  plugin.tx_myext.is_flash_browser = 1  
[global]

# Browser Agent: Safari prior to version 3.  
[useragent = *Safari*] && [version = <3]  
  plugin.tx_myext.is_flash_browser = 1  
[global]

# Browser Agent: iPhone, iPad, iPod  
# Must be at the end to override Safari condition if necessary.  
[useragent = *iPhone*] || [useragent = *iPod*] || [useragent = *iPad*]  
  plugin.tx_myext.is_flash_browser = 0  
[global]
```

**And last but not least in the PHP-Method I used the following code to access the setting:**

```
if ($is_flash_browser == 1) {  
  // Here comes the flash player stuff.  
} else {  
  // Here comes the HTML5 player stuff.  
}
```